# Foobar Bringing a Gun to a Guard Fight Optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm thinking through the challenge ["Bringing a Gun to a Guard Fight" by Google Foobar](https://peter-ak.github.io/2020/05/10/Brining_a_gun_to_a_guard_fight.html) (also defined at the bottom of the question for convenience).

I came to the same conclusion in the article linked, that it is best to solve the problem by reflecting the room. However, the article suggests that we first generate a box of mirrored rooms, where the height and width is defined by the max number of times we can mirror the room upwards and sideways within the gun distance (`ceil((player_position + laser distance) / room_size)`). We would then remove all the parts that are diagonally outside the box

However, this is prone to inefficiency as we must generate many more points than the gun distance would allow. As the gun distance increases, this inefficiency would increase.

However, I am unable to find any way around this problem. What is the optimal way to generate the points for the problem?

> ===============================
>
> Uh-oh - you've been cornered by one of Commander Lambdas elite guards!
> Fortunately, you grabbed a beam weapon from an abandoned guard post
> while you were running through the station, so you have a chance to
> fight your way out. But the beam weapon is potentially dangerous to
> you as well as to the elite guard: its beams reflect off walls,
> meaning you'll have to be very careful where you shoot to avoid
> bouncing a shot toward yourself!
>
> Luckily, the beams can only travel a certain maximum distance before
> becoming too weak to cause damage. You also know that if a beam hits a
> corner, it will bounce back in exactly the same direction. And of
> course, if the beam hits either you or the guard, it will stop
> immediately (albeit painfully).
>
> Write a function solution(dimensions, your_position, guard_position,
> distance) that gives an array of 2 integers of the width and height of
> the room, an array of 2 integers of your x and y coordinates in the
> room, an array of 2 integers of the guard's x and y coordinates in the
> room, and returns an integer of the number of distinct directions that
> you can fire to hit the elite guard, given the maximum distance that
> the beam can travel.
>
> The room has integer dimensions [1 < x_dim <= 1250, 1 < y_dim <=
> 1250]. You and the elite guard are both positioned on the integer
> lattice at different distinct positions (x, y) inside the room such
> that [0 < x < x_dim, 0 < y < y_dim]. Finally, the maximum distance
> that the beam can travel before becoming harmless will be given as an
> integer 1 < distance <= 10000.
>
> For example, if you and the elite guard were positioned in a room with
> dimensions [3, 2], your_position [1, 1], guard_position [2, 1], and a
> maximum shot distance of 4, you could shoot in seven different
> directions to hit the elite guard (given as vector bearings from your
> location): [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3,
> -2]. As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2]
> bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the
> elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at
> bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the elite
> guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(5).
>
> Test cases
> ==========
> Your code should pass the following test cases. Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.
>
> **Python cases**
>
> Input: solution.solution([3,2], [1,1], [2,1], 4) Output:   7
>
> Input: solution.solution([300,275], [150,150], [185,100], 500) Output:
> 9

Answer (score 0):

Generating the next room is just mirroring it in a chosen direction. We then have two new points, one for the guard and one for ourselves. We can do this as an iteration, room by room with constant space and time. A method that worked for me, although not trivial to code, was to hash the line (from origin-us to the newly mirrored guard) since we need to be able to determine if the new point is on a line we already fired and hit a guard on, along with some other checks.

Also, since we traverse room by room, we can just stop when the distance is too great without generating extra rooms.

There is a least one published code that looks a lot more compact than what I suggested, which I did not understand. It looked like it was generalizing the transformations but I couldn't follow it.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a code example? I'm not sure I understand how hashing the line helps

Comment: @nii75435eoopy for foobar, I would rather not provide code. If we are shooting at a guard there are two points, the origin point, which is the location in the input provided for we are standing. And a second point, where the guard is standing, for which there is one in every mirrored room as we traverse. The origin point is the same. Two points form a line, who's equation parameters we can hash.

Comment: @nii75435eoopy clearly if we shoot on the same line, we can only hit the closest instance of a guard on that line.

Comment: Ah I see. I presumed the optimization was something beyond that. I had already implemented that in my final submission. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

`ceil((player_position + laser distance) / room_size)` is not enough

For the following case where :

```
solution([20, 20], [2, 2], [2, 4], 5)
```

you would still need to create a reflection for the left side

I found that this formula works better:

```
x_reflect = max(int(float(your_position[0] + distance) / dimensions[0]), abs(int(floor(float(your_position[0] - distance) / dimensions[0]))))
y_reflect = max(int(float(your_position[1] + distance) / dimensions[1]), abs(int(floor(float(your_position[1] - distance) / dimensions[1]))))
```

I would have written it as a comment but I don't have enough points